# merge information from duplicate records in python

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

Giving this Data sample, I would like to deduplicate rows by mergin info by one column and not by deleting rows. In this case would be the field CODE.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CODE':['000', '111','111','222','222', '333'],'NAME':['help','foo','bar', 'bla','booo','nyaa']  ,'ALT_NAME':['zzz','foo 1','bar', 'bl','bo','rrr'] })
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    ALT_NAME    CODE    NAME
0   zzz         000     help
1   foo 1       111     foo
2   bar         111     bar
3   bl          222     bla
4   bo          222     booo
5   rrr         333     nyaa
```

The result would be:

```
    ALT_NAME        CODE            NAME
0   zzz             000             help
1   [foo 1, bar]    [111,111]       [foo,bar]
2   [bl,bo]         [222,222]       [bla,boo]
3   rrr             333             nyaa
```

Im near to the solution but i can not reach it:

**clue:**

```
df.groupby('CODE')['ALT_NAME','NAME'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

But this is not working for several columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CODE':['000', '111','111','222','222', '333'],'NAME':['help','foo','bar', 'bla','booo','nyaa']  ,'ALT_NAME':['zzz','foo 1','bar', 'bl','bo','rrr'] })
print (df)
```

Output:

```
  ALT_NAME CODE  NAME
0      zzz  000  help
1    foo 1  111   foo
2      bar  111   bar
3       bl  222   bla
4       bo  222  booo
5      rrr  333  nyaa
```

In my opinion better is create lists woth all values by [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) but first create `index` by column with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index('CODE', drop=False)
         .rename_axis(None)
         .groupby('CODE')
         .agg(list)
         .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df1)
```

Output:

```
       ALT_NAME         NAME
0           zzz         help
1  [foo 1, bar]   [foo, bar]
2      [bl, bo]  [bla, booo]
3           rrr         nyaa
```

But if need it add `if-else` to lambda function:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('CODE', drop=False)
         .rename_axis(None)
         .groupby(level=0)
         .agg(lambda x: list(x) if len(x) > 1 else x)
         .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df1)
```

Output:

```
       ALT_NAME        CODE         NAME
0           zzz         000         help
1  [foo 1, bar]  [111, 111]   [foo, bar]
2      [bl, bo]  [222, 222]  [bla, booo]
3           rrr         333         nyaa
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this works for you, `agg` is alias of `aggregate` which is applied to each column of the group:

```
 df.groupby(['CODE']).agg(lambda x:list(x))
```

BTW, does anyone know why it failed when I run `df.groupby(['CODE']).agg(list)`?

Comment: Maybe problem with your pandas version, try upgrade.

Comment: SMART and SHORT!

Comment: I tried ipython 6.4.0 / Ubuntu 16.04, it worked fine. Thank you @jezrael. (and failed when running with ipython 6.2.1 / Windows)